# How do I gain access to the persistance store file of my app which is on my ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I gain access to the persistance store file of my app which is on my ipad?

I need to drop into this Core Data viewer that I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) can help you with that.

Or you can use Xcode's Organizer, just go the devices tab, select the ipad expand the device and klick applications.
From there select the application and export the file you want.